# layer draw for specific element kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs

I use group for adding 25 cells (http://clip2net.com/s/5QZ8vq)
This group belongs to layer.
I want to change background color for first cell, so i use setFill, and then
redraw layer (layer.draw() method) to see the change.

i think it is bad approach to redraw whole layer.
I must use layer for each cell, at the same time, i cant 
use nested layers - http://clip2net.com/s/5R0b0M

Is there workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your project requires it, you can leave all the cells on the same layer.

Canvas is fast enough at redrawing to handle what you've shown in your link.

If you're not moving the cell while re-filling, you can use layer.drawScene instead of layer.draw.

That way you're just redrawing the visible canvas and not redrawing the hidden hit canvas.